# Symfony2 Console Output without OutputInterface

Tags: symfony

I am trying to print some Information to the Console in a Symfony Console Command. Regularly you would do something like this:

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $name = $input->getArgument('name');
    if ($name) {
        $text = 'Hello '.$name;
    } else {
        $text = 'Hello';
    }

    if ($input->getOption('yell')) {
        $text = strtoupper($text);
    }

    $output->writeln($text);
}
```

[For the full Code of the Example - Symfony Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html#creating-a-basic-command)

Unfortunately I can't access the `OutputInterface`. Is it possible to print a Message to the Console?

Unfortunately I can't pass the `OutputInterface` to the Class where I want to print some Output.

Comment: Why can't you *"access"* the OutputInterface?

Comment: Because I only can manipulate a Class that is called in the Command. Unfortunately I don't get passed the `OutputInterface`.

Comment: If no `OutputInterface` were given, PHP would throw an error. Are you using `Symfony\Component\Console\Application` to run them ? Or is it a custom caller ?

Comment: @Touki You misunderstand me. I use a given `Command`. Actually I want to print some Debug message in my Fixtures https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle. I am only able to create the Fixtures Class and there is no `OutputInterface` available.

Comment: What's wrong with `echo` while debugging ? If you want to run the command and output console messages you can use `$command = new MyCommand; $command->run(new ArrayInput($parameters), new ConsoleOutput());`

Comment: Right now I feel like the biggest fool on earth. I didn't tried `echo()`because I thought it won't work. Post this as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Understanding the matter of ponctual debugging, you can always print debug messages with `echo` or `var_dump`

If you plan to use a command without Symfony's application with global debug messages, here's a way to do this.

Symfony offers 3 different `OutputInterface`s

- [NullOutput](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Console/Output/NullOutput.html) - Will result in no output at all and keep the command quiet
- [ConsoleOutput](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Console/Output/ConsoleOutput.html) - Will result in console messages
- [StreamOutput](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Console/Output/StreamOutput.html) - Will result in printing messages into a given stream

### Debugging to a file

Doing such, whenever you call `$output->writeln()` in your command, it will write a new line in `/path/to/debug/file.log`

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\StreamOutput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;
use Acme\FooBundle\Command\MyCommand;

$params = array();
$input  = new ArrayInput($params);

$file   = '/path/to/debug/file.log';
$handle = fopen($file, 'w+');
$output = new StreamOutput($handle);

$command = new MyCommand;
$command->run($input, $output);

fclose($handle);
```

### Debugging in the console

It is quietly the same process, except that you use `ConsoleOutput` instead

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;
use Acme\FooBundle\Command\MyCommand;

$params = array();
$input  = new ArrayInput($params);

$output = new ConsoleOutput();

$command = new MyCommand;
$command->run($input, $output);
```

### No debugging

No message will be printed

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\NullOutput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;
use Acme\FooBundle\Command\MyCommand;

$params = array();
$input  = new ArrayInput($params);

$output = new NullOutput();

$command = new MyCommand;
$command->run($input, $output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at JMSAopBundle https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSAopBundle and check out this great article http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2013/07/symfony2-rich-console-command-output-using-aop/

Comment: This seems pretty promising as well. Maybe I will try it in the next days. Thank you for sharing this ressource. I didn't know about Aop at all.